# how to replace string "[quote]" to only " and [/quote] to "

Tags: java, android, regex

I need to replace all `[quote]` to `"` and `[/quote]` to `"` of following string:

```
[quote]fgfhfgh [quote] vbbb[/quote]ghhhhjj[/quote]
```

The result should be like :

```
"fghfdgfdh "gghj vbbb"ghhhhjj"
```

I used this but unable to do:

```
finalRecieveString = (String) uivdHashTable.get("pendingString");
String ReplaceQuote=finalRecieveString.replaceAll("[quote]", "\"");
ReplaceFinalQuoteString=ReplaceQuote.replaceAll("[/quote]", "\"");
```

Comment: Please take care to format your questions! Use the bottons provided and the preview below your question.... I'll try and fix it up a bit, but still...

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape square brackets, as `replaceAll()` expects regexp which brackets are part of syntax of. So try:

```
finalRecieveString = (String) uivdHashTable.get("pendingString");
String ReplaceQuote=finalRecieveString.replaceAll("\[quote\]", "\"");
ReplaceFinalQuoteString=ReplaceQuote.replaceAll("\[/quote\]", "\"");
```

You could also chain the replace:

```
ReplaceFinalQuoteString = finalRecieveString.replaceAll("\[quote\]", "\"").replaceAll("\[/quote\]", "\"");
```

PS: adding spaces around "=" increases code readability.

Answer (score 0):

String string = "[quote]mucho grando wrote: [quote]mucho grando wrote: vbbb[/quote]ghhhhjj[/quote]";

String tmp_str = string.replace("\[quote]", "\"");

String str_ans = tmp_str.replace("\[/quote]", "\"");

your ans  **str_ans**  = "mucho grando wrote: "mucho grando wrote: vbbb"ghhhhjj"